# Finding two associated indexes where the sum of two elements equals a target value

Tags: c++, algorithm

**Background:**

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

**Example:**

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,

return [0, 1].

**Question:**

I have a list of numbers 1,2,3,4,5. My target value is 8, so I should return indices  2 and 4. My first thought is to write a a double for loop that checks to see if adding two elements from the list will get my target value. Although, when checking to see if there is such a solution, my code returns that there is none.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    vector<int> list;
    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_back(3);
    list.push_back(4);
    list.push_back(5);

    int target = 8;


    string result;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if(list[i] + list[j] == target) {
                result = "There is a solution";
            }
            else {
                result = "There is no solution";
            }
        }

    }

    cout << result << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Perhaps my approach/thinking is plain wrong. Could anyone provide any hints or suggestions to solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct but you are forgetting you are in a loop that continues after finding the solution.

This will get you halfway there.  I recommend putting both loops in a function, and returning once you find a match.  One thing you could do is return a `pair<int,int>` from that function or you could simply output the results from within that point in the loop.

```
bool solutionFound = false;
int i,j;

for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
{
    for(j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) 
    {
        if(list[i] + list[j] == target) 
        {
            solutionFound = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the function approach might look like:

```
pair<int, int> findSolution(vector<int> list, int target)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
  {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++)
    {
      if (list[i] + list[j] == target)
      {
        return pair<int, int>(i, j);
      }
    }
  }
  return pair<int, int>(-1, -1);
}

int main() {

  vector<int> list;
  list.push_back(1);
  list.push_back(2);
  list.push_back(3);
  list.push_back(4);
  list.push_back(5);

  int target = 8;
  pair<int, int> results = findSolution(list, target);
  cout << results.first << " " << results.second << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the C++ incorporating Dave's answer for linear execution time and a couple helpful comments:

```
pair<int, int> findSolution(vector<int> list, int target)
{
  unordered_map<int, int> valueToIndex;
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
  {
    int needed = target - list[i];
    auto it = valueToIndex.find(needed);
    if (it != valueToIndex.end())
    {
      return pair<int, int>(it->second, i);
    }
    valueToIndex.emplace(list[i], i);
  }
  return pair<int, int>(-1, -1);
}

int main() 
{
  vector<int> list = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
  int target = 10;
  pair<int, int> results = findSolution(list, target);
  cout << results.first << " " << results.second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: You need to break from the outer loop as well.

Comment: Times like this it's usually easier to place the loops in their own function so you can bail out with a single `return` statement.

Comment: I see, what is the if statement at the bottom suppose to do? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Quick question, as I am constantly trying to improve my C++. Do you have any recommendations on how to improve ones skills? I am doing an advanced course in C++ on udemy.com and reading C++ books. Although, I was thinking there are better ways then doing tutorials and reading. Any advice, is appreciated.

Comment: @Wolfy Hmm, I'm 20 years in with C++, so...not really.  Although all the `std::` (maps, vectors, etc) stuff I learned in about a couple weeks porting...hilariously enough..a very complex ruby program to C++.  So that's always a good way.  Problem with that approach is it tends to leave huge gaps in your knowledge.  Books are a great way to fill in those gaps and get a better foundation.

Comment: Thanks, yea I believe practice just makes you better so I will keep doing what I am doing. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing this in n^2 time. Solve it in linear time by hashing each element, and checking each element to see if it's complement wrt. the total you're trying to achieve is in the hash.

E.g., for  1,2,3,4,5, with a target of 8

```
indx 0, val 1: 7 isn't in the map; H[1] = 0
indx 1, val 2: 6 isn't in the map, H[2] = 1
indx 2, val 3: 5 isn't in the map, H[3] = 2
indx 3, val 4: 4 isn't in the map, H[4] = 3
indx 4, val 5: 3 is in the map. H[3] = 2. Return 2,4
```

Code, as requested (Ruby)

```
def get_indices(arr, target)
    value_to_index = {}
    arr.each_with_index do |val, index|
        if value_to_index.has_key?(target - val)
            return [value_to_index[target - val], index] 
        end
        value_to_index[val] = index
    end
end

get_indices([1,2,3,4,5], 8)
```

Comment: I doubt the OP is following, and the solution *I'm* thinking of wouldn't be faster for a single run or for small sets, and would be harder to read.  So I suspect I'm not following either.  Code?

Comment: @zzxyz Done. This takes up linear time and linear space. The double loop takes n^2 time and constant space.

Comment: I am following. I know using an unordered_map can achieve what you are suggesting. I will optimize it once I understand how to use that STL. Thanks.

Comment: @Wolfy Ah good. And didn't mean to throw shade. Dave, thanks. Ruby hurts my brain, but I get it now. And yeah, that's much better than the way I was thinking.

Comment: @Wolfy - I incorporated this delightful answer into my own, mostly just because I really liked it and wanted to see it running.

Comment: @zzxyz Thank you for that, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same as zzxyz's most recent edit but a little quicker and dirtier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool FindSolution(const std::vector<int> &list, // const reference. Less copying
                  int target)
{
    for (int i: list) // Range-based for (added in C++11)
    {
        for (int j: list)
        {
            if (i + j == target) // i and j are the numbers from the vector. 
                                 // no need for indexing
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> list{1,2,3,4,5}; // Uniform initialization Added in C++11. 
                                      // No need for push-backs of fixed data

    if (FindSolution(list, 8))
    {
        std::cout << "There is a solution\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "There is no solution\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```